# Force angular js app on heroku to use http instead of https?

Tags: angularjs, http, heroku, https

I am querying an "http" API with my app, so every time I access my application on heroku (which is https enabled by default), CORS complains about cross-origin domain requests.

Asking the owner of the API to make it "https" is not an option, so I was wondering if it was possible to force my application to always use http? This is a node.js built application. (More specifically, it is a yeoman-generated angular js app). In Rails, I've seen several posts on Stack OverFlow saying this can be easily done with something like `config.force_ssl = false`, so I was wondering whether something similar could work for a node.js application (either something in the code or on Heroku specifically).

Comment: if you must serve your app from https you could use your server as proxy to make calls to other api

Answer (score 0):

As a fix, I wrote an AngularJS Factory that routes all `https` requests to `http`:

```
  .factory('DisableSSL', function($location, $window){
    return {
      activate: function() {
        if ($location.protocol() !== 'http') {
          $window.location.href = $location.absUrl().replace('https', 'http');
        }
      }
    };
  })
```

This factory is included in all of my other controllers and the `activate` function is called.

Note that this doesn't work if you're using a browser extension like [HTTPSEverywhere](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/https-everywhere/gcbommkclmclpchllfjekcdonpmejbdp?hl=en).